# How do I make the join between two streams on Spark structured streaming? - Java 8

Tags: java-8, outer-join, spark-structured-streaming

I know, join between two streams is not supported yet. But there's a way to do it anyway?
Or I need to wait for Spark 2.2.0?
Thank you

Comment: Did you find a way to do this with structured streaming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark 2.2.0 still won't support stream-stream join. You can watch this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18791

Comment: will it be available in 2.3 ?

Comment: Yes. 2.3 will support it.

Comment: Hi! I was just playing with spark 2.3 RC4 stream-stream join. Somehow I couldn't do a self join on streaming dataframe easily. and I am not sure why..It might be my syntax but I am not sure..more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900127/how-to-do-a-self-join-in-spark-2-3-0-what-is-the-correct-syntax would be great if you can help on this one!!

Answer (score 1):

As of production release of Spark 2.3, [stream-stream joins](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins) are now supported in structured streaming.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you using Kafka Streams rather than Structured Spark Streaming if you want to join streams.. [check this link to see how this can be done](https://www.confluent.io/blog/distributed-real-time-joins-and-aggregations-on-user-activity-events-using-kafka-streams/)

Comment: Thank you, but I've already used Kafka Streams. I want to try some different streaming engines for specific reason :D