# How to do a self join in Spark 2.3.0? What is the correct syntax?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger 

val jdf = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "join_test").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load();   
jdf.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
val resultdf = spark.sql("select * from table as x inner join table as y on x.offset=y.offset")
resultdf.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000)).start()
```

and I get the following exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`x.offset`' given input columns: [x.value, x.offset, x.key, x.timestampType, x.topic, x.timestamp, x.partition]; line 1 pos 50;
'Project [*]
+- 'Join Inner, ('x.offset = 'y.offset)
   :- SubqueryAlias x
   :  +- SubqueryAlias table
   :     +- StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@15f3f9cf,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(startingOffsets -> earliest, subscribe -> join_test, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> localhost:9092),None), kafka, [key#28, value#29, topic#30, partition#31, offset#32L, timestamp#33, timestampType#34]
   +- SubqueryAlias y
      +- SubqueryAlias table
         +- StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@15f3f9cf,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(startingOffsets -> earliest, subscribe -> join_test, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> localhost:9092),None), kafka, [key#28, value#29, topic#30, partition#31, offset#32L, timestamp#33, timestampType#34]
```

I have changed the code to this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger 

val jdf = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "join_test").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load();
val jdf1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "join_test").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load();

jdf.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
jdf1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

val resultdf = spark.sql("select * from table inner join table1 on table.offset=table1.offset")

resultdf.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000)).start()
```

And this works. However, I don't believe it is the solution I am looking for. I want to be able to do a self join using raw SQL but not by making additional copies of a dataframe like the code above. so is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue and will be fixed in 2.4.0. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23406. Right now you can just avoid to join the same DataFrame objects.

Comment: Ahhh!! got it! Thanks for that.  It's hard for me to avoid join on the same DataFrame objects mainly because I get raw sql from our users and the raw sql can contain any number of self joins so I would have to parse the raw sql first and then try to create whatever number of dataframe objects and all that so it would turn into a bit complex thing. I see that a PR is already created so can I just cherry-pick that into 2.3 or may be compile and use the master breanch? This feature is very important for us and Spark 2.4 can take another 5 months from now..so wondering if I got any luck?

Comment: If you are building Spark by yourself, then you can definitely cherry-pick it into your own 2.3 branch. The reason that the community doesn't merge it into 2.3 is mostly the change in this patch is non trivial and Spark 2.3.0 is being voted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question on this..should I create a branch of from master or branch-2.3 ? I just want 2.3 plus that one commit that fixes the self-joins.

Comment: I feel like branching off from master is a bit risky to deploy in our production since spark master branch will be constantly evolving and I can run it incompatible jars issue such as kafka and so on. so need to fork off from a branch that can remain stable as much as 2.3 is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the DataFrame API [`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#join-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-) function instead of using SQL syntax:

```
jdf.as("df1").join(jdf.as("df2"), $"df1.offset" === $"df2.offset", "inner")
```

Comment: same exact exception `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`df1.offset`' given input columns: [df1.partition, df1.timestampType, df1.topic, df1.timestamp, df1.value, df1.offset, df1.key];;`

Comment: Just an FYI I am trying to do streaming join (as you can see from my code). Whether streaming or non-streaming doesn't seem to matter. The syntax for self join doesn't seem to work in either case. And I am getting same exact exception. I tried non-streaming version of self join in Spark 2.2.0 also and I get the same exact error!!

Comment: @user1870400: Are you working with streaming datasets? according to the documentation, joins between two streaming datasets are not yet supported.

Comment: I am using Spark 2.3 and they are supported in 2.3 RC4. Spark 2.3 is not release yet but release candidate 4 is available here https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/spark/v2.3.0-rc4-bin/